# Is user silently kicked out of review system for short period of time?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

I know there are audit items in the reviews that users do so that to check whether or not the user is paying attention to this. I have been more on the reviewing side for past 2 months and have come across-ed these hidden gems 4-5 times. And probably I have passed each time as I envisage the user is not given any notification if he fails in them.

For past 2 days I am seeing the following behaviour -

I see very few 2-3 posts in review queue that I am eligible for, I hit the queue and review them. Such things continue several times for couple of hours. But since 2 days I see 0 number of posts to review in each queue.

I don't think I might have failed in any of the hidden tricky posts as I do pay attention to each post.

Is it a user is silently kicked for a short while and then he sees the posts in review queue?

Also is it that the review queue is distributed geographically. I mean I see new users being shown in the recent reviewer list but I had been seen 0- post to review at that time. This is a observation over a period of time, so just a assumption.

Please clarify on above points.

Comment: Dupe or related: [Are certain users favored the opportunity to review posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165266)

Comment: A **hidden gem** is a good thing. When reviewing a first post or late answer you might discover a really good one, that you wanted to vote up, or even share by tweeting or whatever. What you have come across 4 or 5 times are **review audits**.

Comment: @Kate ok so I misinterpreted hidden gems with review audits. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it a user is silently kicked for a short while and then he sees the posts in review queue?

No, it's not really silent. If you fail too many audits, you'll see something like this:

[image: review ban message]

Once the time has expired, you'll see the review queues as you normally would, with whatever number of items remains in them.

Comment: _If (?)_ the OP is indeed banned isn't this question a dupe of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158675/why-am-i-getting-the-message-youve-failed-too-many-recent-review-audits

Comment: The OP isn't banned. If he was, he'd know.