# Serial edit approving; a problem?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-abuse

Well, while approving edits today.. in my opinion I came across a slight problem.  Users serial-approving edits without even checking the content.

I question whether there should be some sort of penalty for this.. if x amount of approvals a user has made have been rejected by every other user doing the approval at the time... lock the privilege or something?

For the record, I do understand there are [various](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167316/somebody-actually-approved-this-edit) other [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted) regarding this very same thing, however in my reading, while there were propositions for dealing with such..  what I had in mind didn't seem to appear.

Comment: There are regular review audits with penalties if you fail too much of them.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe The "penalty" is just an interval when you can't review I believe. Perhaps this needs to be stronger (altogether different discussion though).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's stop with the calling out of specific users. This sort of public shaming never ends well and it looks like a few folks here have already started retaliating.

Just flag one of the user's posts, explain what you're seeing, and let the moderators handle this **privately**.

For what it's worth, we already have an audit system in place that [blocks folks from /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165452/155160) if they fail too many audits.

Comment: I honestly didn't mean for the shaming to happen.  I rarely review and this was the first case I saw.