# Identified Suspected Robo-Reviewer. What now?

Tags: support, review-abuse

I have identified a suspected robo-reviewer. They are spending on average 4 seconds per review, they always select 'No Action Needed', and on a number of occassions, they have done this on obvious NAA posts.

I don't want to name the user here on Meta, but I am wondering how this activity should be highlighted?

I have previously flagged the activity and I believe they received a review ban, but they have now continued to do robo reviews.

Comment: Thanks for not naming and shaming! For further info see this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170103/serial-edit-approving-a-problem

Comment: Now wait. He will eventually fall into the review audit trap and get blocked from reviewing any further.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd that depends on what site Ren is referring to. I don't think the audit trap exists on all sites yet.

Comment: It is on Stack Overflow and the audit trap is in place there :) Ok, I will wait, shouldn't be too long with the way they review.

Comment: Thanks for the flag with the extra details, those were really helpful. There is something very weird going on with this user and the review audits, and we're looking into this further.

Comment: @BradLarson No problem, glad I can help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flag one of their posts with a custom flag, asking for a mod to look into it. Mods can issue a review ban or send a warning to the user if it's borderline.

However, it's not entirely necessary to flag on the [sites which have  review audits in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work). IIRC, the review ban scales up on second offence, so they'll soon be hit with an automated one. Still, it's better to curb this behavior earlier --so flagging is preferable.

Comment: Ok, I will flag it now.

Comment: Also note that flagging is preferable if you suspect that the user is managing to bypass the audits.