# Gratuitous editing

Tags: discussion, badges

Someone changed "MSSQL" to "SQL Server" in one of my questions. I don't care enough to fix it, but I think it's a fairly good example of pointless editing: the question is about obtaining metadata for full-text indexing. This is an advanced topic, and it is product specific. There is absolutely no chance that anyone capable of asking or answering that question would be assisted by spelling out the name, either in understanding the question or in finding it.

"SQL Server" is actually *less* helpful than "MSSQL" because it will cause false positives. "SQL Server" is a class of software that includes Oracle, Sybase SQL Server, MySQL etc, whereas MSSQL positively identifies the one and only database engine pertinent to the question.

So here's the question: is SO a user-maintained knowledge base, or a toy for badge collectors?

---

It has been asked what is the point of the above question. It is to provoke introspection. When newbies don't know all the rules you are quick to stomp their questions on the pretext of curating a knowledgebase, but when you want to play with your button collection, somehow that's different.

This is not a rant. It names no names and draws no conclusions (at least not in the first draft). I merely set up a mirror for you to look at yourselves.

I choose not to rant when I feel bent out of shape because the message would be lost in the anger. This example is mild and didn't offend me, but served nicely to illustrate the point.

Comment: This seems like a rant; but more specifically, this seems like a rant at SO. This is Stack**Exchange**. For questions specific to SO, ask in the SO meta. Be sure to ask *why* such an edit was acceptable (and do not point out that you do not care, because it seems evident from your language choice that you do); the question above, as is, will likely receive heavy downvoting for being non-constructive.

Comment: Gettin' tired of seeing folks harassed for posting on the "wrong" meta, @gnemlock. Are suggested edits really such an obscure topic that they can't be discussed here?

Comment: @Shog9, when you look at the actual question, *"Is SO a user-maintained knowledge base, or a toy for badge collectors"*, you'll find that either a) this question is not about suggested edits as much as it is about the behavior specifically found on SO or b) this question has some serious issues. It seems very obvious that the *true* intention is to find out *why* such an edit was appropriate. How do we know? This is not Stack Overflow.

Comment: So the question is unclear then, @gnemlock. That's a common, specific and addressable problem.

Comment: @Shog9: I hate seeing people get the runaround too, but in this case the post seems to mostly be about three things: the technical merits of the edit, which is SO-specific; whether pointless edits are acceptable, an obvious dupe of the help center and every other bit of guidance on editing everywhere on SE; and a rant about a dumb edit that's not worth reversing but is worth ranting about. All three seem to be valid reasons to close.

Comment: I doubt anyone really wants to debate the merits of the edit, @nathan. It's a ranty question and may not be salvageable for it, but SO-specific is a red herring here.

Comment: You don't care enough to fix it, but you care enough to come here and complain about it? I don't quite understand the thought process there.

Comment: @PeterWone So, I tried to de-rant this a little with a full copy edit, improve the tone and such, but I only got [this far](https://pastebin.com/ZyKeGX7A), and was stumped trying to come up with a different way to express the final sentence. What is your *actual* question here? Also fwiw if somebody makes a bogus edit, you *should* roll it back, and you can leave a description in the edit comment as to why. If it was a *suggested* edit that went through a review, and you feel that it was approved in obvious error, you can also raise a custom flag to draw attention to it, but do this sparingly.

Comment: @Jason the "question" as I see it is a call to discuss what OP considers as pointless/useless edits, done only to gain badges.

Comment: Duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178180/gaming-grinding-copy-editor-badge

Answer (score 7):

> Is SO a user-maintained knowledge base, or a toy for badge collectors?

Both. The nature of the Stack Overflow/Exchange system is that it rewards people with badges and reputation for maintaining a knowledge base. Sometimes people [don't care about the extrinsic motivation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation), sometimes they care a little too much and sometimes people are motivated to both share knowledge and to earn awards. Without knowing which edits in particular you are referring to, I can't tell exactly what sort of user you are dealing with here.

I tend to agree with you (as a former Oracle user) that "SQL Server" is somewhat ambiguous. But it is the official name [Microsoft uses](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2016). "MSSQL" seems kinda weird; I'd want to put a space in there somewhere. I wonder if maybe that's the thinking. Maybe it would be better to say "Microsoft SQL Server" instead, but that's so wordy. Can we just all blame Microsoft for [not acquiring Sybase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#Genesis)?

In the long run, it isn't productive to worry too much about these sorts of edits. We don't always know why people make them. There's a temptation to [assume bad character or intention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_attribution_error), but we really can't know for sure. If the user is suggesting pointless edits, they'll probably get [banned when their edits are rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). If you feel strongly about it, you can rollback edits yourself.