# Last reviewer name is missing in closed question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

Today while reviewing close questions, I closed a question(where I was the last person to review) but it was not updated in the sticky bar saying "This item is no longer reviewable" whereas it was updated in below bar stating "put on hold as off-topic by...."

Even after refresh, it was not showing.  I even tried as an anonymous user, still it is not getting updated.

[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3425729) you can see happened in most of closed questions.

Comment: Are you sure you closed it from the review screen? Perhaps you opened the question in a new tab and voted to close from there? I've done this many times myself...

Comment: @animuson I think so.  Now a same thing happened it was working correctly.  Let me check it and let you know.

Comment: @animuson You're right.  May I know why it is not getting updated?  Is it by design?

Comment: Only actions taken directly from the review screen count towards the review. If you do something outside of that screen, it doesn't get recorded for review.

Comment: @animuson But in `below bar stating "put on hold as off-topic by...."` it is showing my name.

Comment: Because you voted to close. You can go vote to close on any question, but if you don't do it directly on the review page, it won't count as a review.

Comment: @animuson I got it.  Similarly when I closed a question directly then I came to "close review" tab, I tried to close it showed me a message "already closed...".  Then just to test, I clicked "Leave open" it got processed.  Is this a valid behavior?

Comment: @animuson so... [meta-tag:status-bydesign]? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number one thing to keep in mind: if you don't see the `/review` in the URL on the page you're currently on, your action is *not* going to count towards review. I often catch myself opening the question in a new tab to investigate further, forgetting that I had originally stumbled upon this in the review queue, and taking action on the post itself rather than on the review item. You'll still be listed as a user who voted to close, because you *did* vote to close, but you *didn't* review.

As for your comment about casting a Leave Open vote: That is an alteration of an older bug where users can continue to [submit actions to a review item for an infinite length of time after review had already completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198791/how-is-this-user-able-to-review-posts-so-long-after-they-were-completed-original). It *was* fixed for a short time, but the fix was retracted. Obviously you can't submit a Close vote since the post is already closed, but that doesn't prevent you from submitting some other action which is not validated at all.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)