# Technical criteria for review queues

Tags: support, review

What are the current (technical) criteria for filtering posts into the review queues?

The FAQ [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/168244) covers some general discussion on the queues (but no specifics). Also, [New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139536/168244) mentions some vague selection criteria ("algorithmically determined...") and targets only specific queues. However, while some queues seem fairly obvious in their implementation, there are still [questions as to why certain posts end up in a review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198791/168244).

This post originates from a [Bug in how new user status is calculated](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4310/5764) where an existing, well-established user posted an answer to old question yet ended up in a late review queue (designated to catch "new user's answer to an old question"). Admittedly this user is [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com)'s [top investor](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/173062/top-investors) and frequently dips into the low-rep end of the pool as a result:

[image]