# Author reviewing edit after it has already been rejected

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

[One of my edits](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/253248) was recently rejected on Ask Different. Two people rejected it, but then the OP reviewed it as "Edit".

[image: edit]

Is this intentional behaviour or a bug?

Comment: This is deliberate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028

Comment: This is intentional. I believe OP's decision overrides reviews.

Comment: Why in the world are you trying to prohibit people from seeing the actual review.  How is that *possibly* helpful?

Comment: Yes, OP or moderator can review reviews and change outcome.

Comment: @Servy What do you mean?

Comment: @DManokhin Rolling back the edit that links to the actual review, for...apparently no reason.

Comment: @Servy I added a link. I wanted the image and link to be visible

Comment: Most edit suggestions are rejected on Ask Different. It is a feature of that site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike what was said in the comments, this is *not* a case where the author overrode the rejection. In that case, the only option presented to the author would have been "approve", and the outcome of the edit would have changed to "approved".

What likely happened here, as evidenced by the fact that the "edit" and the second rejection happened at approximately the same time, was that the author was notified about the suggested edit, and clicked to review it when only one user had rejected it. Then, they opted to click the "Improve Edit" button, but before they could submit their improvement, a second user voted to reject it. (Since the review was already completed, that may be why the Community user also didn't vote to approve it.)

The [system allows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198791/how-is-this-user-able-to-review-posts-so-long-after-they-were-completed-original/268592#268592) users to submit reviews to posts if they loaded the task while it was still reviewable, but didn't submit their review until after review had completed.

Ordinarily, this circumstance is prevented by a 3-minute "exclusivity" period on each suggested edit, wherein when someone first loads a suggested edit, no one will be shown the task in the review queue. The author likely took more than three minutes to make their improvement, so the exclusivity period ended and another user was presented the task in the queue.

Comment: "The author likely took more than three minutes to make their improvement, so the exclusivity period ended and another user was presented the task in the queue." More likely the second reviewer opened the review, then the author went to it and started editing it, then the reviewer rejected it, then the author submitted their edit.  Your proposal would work too, but jumping through all of those hoops isn't needed to reproduce this.