# When to post on Stack Exchange meta, when to post on [site] meta

Tags: discussion, support, meta, per-site-meta

After browsing some questions here some of them are site specific. Should they be posted here or on that site's meta?

If you post it here the question could get more attention from a wider audience but otherwise I’m not sure.

Comment: Are you looking at old questions? Some of them may come from the period where the Stack Overflow meta, was also the global network-wide meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from what's written in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), if you have a question, ask yourself whether it concerns the specific site or the whole network.

On a site meta, questions about the site's scope and policies are on topic. Also requests to close or reopen questions, tags etc. These are all topics that each stack has to decide for themselves (or already did).

On MSE, ask questions that concern other sites, too. For example, feature requests that would bring a change for every user on the network.

E. g. let's look at your previous [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320151/377968) about the rejected edit. It was about the mechanism underlying the suggested edits review process and so it was fine to post here. If you had wanted to know *why* your edit was rejected, Ask Different's meta would have been more appropriate instead, because it is more about a site's policy.

There is sometimes some overlap. For example, you could start a discussion on a possible feature on a site's meta and see if you can get support. And if you got it, you can take it to MSE. Here is an [example](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5754/75187).

Maybe to expand a bit on Bart's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320155/when-to-post-on-stack-exchange-meta-when-to-post-on-site-meta/320158#comment1048382_320155): This was once (also) the meta for Stack Overflow. Here is the [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888/377968) announcing the split into Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange. That's also why you can still find old posts that are pretty SO-specific (talking about tags, or why a question was closed / deleted etc.).