# Improving tag wiki edits leads to design bug; rejecting throws a blank excerpt

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

When improving a tag wiki edit on *[Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)* (SFF), I noticed what looks like a design bug: the excerpt field and edit reasons don't have the same width, and more importantly, the excerpt is slightly hidden behind the "What is a tag wiki excerpt?" panel.

[image: Design bug on improve edit page]

[In chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7688465#7688465), user rene indicated that it was a repro for them, with the excerpt being completely blank (observation made on [this test edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/64449)):

[image: Blank excerpt when rejecting]

Steps to reproduce, suggest a tag wiki edit, select "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit" upon reviewing.

---

Reproduced on Firefox 66.0.3, Windows 7. and on Edge.

---

I'm not actually sure those are the same bugs, as on the second screenshot, the excerpt field and edit reason field are nicely aligned and there's no overlaying panel. Please split the two reports if needed.

Comment: Also in Edge there is an issue, but there the field is too small, just as it is in Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnjes.png

Comment: For me in Edge, the Improve Edit UI looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5I46.png), and the Reject and Edit UI looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16rrI.png). Both show misaligned fields, but the first one otherwise has no bugs; it seems like that's a site-specific issue. I can fully reproduce your issue in the latter case. (By the way, if you're wondering how I got those screenshots despite having <20k rep, I [fudged the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268592) to force the UI to appear; not sure what happens if I actually attempt to go through with it.)

Comment: I can't reproduce either of these issues anymore; the editor UI seems to display properly when improving a tag wiki edit, as well as for rejecting a tag wiki edit (when the previous version of the edit is not blank, clicking "Reject and Edit" doesn't show a blank editor). As such, I'm retagging this as [status-completed]. Feel free to re-escalate it or post a new bug report if it's still occurring.