# Why did my First Post review not count?

Tags: support, review

I was doing a review in the First Posts queue on Interpersonal Skills. I spent several minutes finding the appropriate meta links and putting together a nice comment for the new user to help guide them in how to improve their answer. Once I posted the comments, I clicked "I'm Done" to finish the review, but then I noticed that my review count didn't go up. Checking the stats tab confirms that I have 0 completed reviews in that queue today.

[image]

I looked at the history tab and saw that another user had completed the review (presumably by flagging the post as there were no votes or other comments and the status was "reviewed") during the time that I was composing a comment. I understand that it only takes one reviewer to "complete" a review in the first posts queue, but if I see something in the queue and go through the actions needed to review it, shouldn't I still get credit for reviewing the post even though I'm not the one who completed it?

Comment: Did you wait for some time before re-checking?

Comment: Yes, it's been an hour since I posted the comments on the question according to the timestamps and I still see 0 completed reviews for myself today

Comment: One review is enough for [First Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581/377968), then it [gets removed for all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/377968). But each "user has their own copy of the queue". So it may look like you are still reviewing, when you don't. I remember complaints from *suggested edits* reviewers who reviewed bad edits just to find out afterwards that robo reviewers had already approved it.

Comment: @AnneDaunted This seems like it would be counter-productive as it incentivizes taking a fast action in the queue (such as no action needed) when a slower action such as leaving a comment is the better action to take.

Comment: It opens again after 5 minutes (which should be enough to do a proper review IMHO).

Comment: @Glorfindel For most reviews I would agree, but when it comes to leaving a comment on IPS, I often spend more than 5 minutes trying to get the comment right because the new user experience there can be particularly challenging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably made your review more than 15 minutes after the other user finished making their review.

The system generally allows users to submit reviews after a task is already completed in order to give credit to all users who are reviewing a given post at the same time. However, if it's been more than 15 minutes since the review task was completed, your review will intentionally [silently fail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322015/377214) and not be submitted.

Previously, there was no such limit: all reviews submitted after the post completed review would be counted. However, this limit was implemented in response to people [exploiting this loophole](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268592/377214) to submit fake reviews on long-completed tasks in order to game the system to earn review badges. Basically, it was decided that any review submitted more than 15 minutes after the task was completed is very likely to come from someone who's gaming the system rather than someone who was legitimately reviewing a task at the same time as someone else.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I've been known to take 30 minutes to an hour in some instances to write a comment.

Comment: @Rainbacon In that case, I suggest casting some sort of vote to complete the review task, *then* compose and post your comment. That said, this can be an accessibility issue, and maybe it's a good idea to make a question asking about it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is unfortunate and that you're a victim of the system. The 5 minutes delay is there to make sure posts can get a speedy review, even if you decide to leave the review item in a pending state to fetch coffee, write another post or walk the dog. That's why another user browsing the queues gets to the review item, too.

The problem with your proposal "if I see something in the queue and go through the actions needed to review it, shouldn't I still get credit for reviewing the post even though I'm not the one who completed it?" is that we've had users in the past who opened a lot of review items and then submitted their reviews very late (maybe even after checking what other reviewers did - once a review is completed, it becomes public).

Note that I *have* seen instances where a First Post or Late Answer is reviewed twice, e.g. [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/81480). <s>So what exactly the conditions are when your review counts or not is unclear to me.</s> it's 15 minutes, thanks @Sonic. Even for Interpersonal Skills, that should be enough to give proper attention to a first post.

Comment: See my answer. I address this situation directly.

Comment: Also, the 3-minute "checkout" period only applies to the Suggested Edits queue, not to other queues.