# Descriptions for review task result types 22 and 23 are swapped in SEDE

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, data-explorer

The descriptions for [review task result types](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1214160/reviewtaskresulttypes) 22 and 23 are swapped in the Data Explorer.

For context, these are the internal database numbers used to indicate the type of review someone made on a post in any review queue, and are global to all review queues. 22 and 23 are used to indicate when an author or a moderator has chosen to override the outcome of a suggested edit.

As the table below says, review type ID 22 is named `SuggestedEditOverrideToApproved`, and based on that name, it's used for overriding a previously *rejected* edit into an approved one. [Testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268592/377214) confirms that that's the case. (The system, being security-minded, didn't let me actually submit the review, but did show me a dialog box which was the right way around.)

However, the description in SEDE has it the wrong way around: it says "Previously approved suggested edit has been rejected".

Similarly, review type ID 23 is named `SuggestedEditOverrideToRejected`. Based on that name, it's used for overriding a previously *approved* edit into a rejected one, and the same testing method confirms that that's the case. But the description incorrectly states "Previously rejected suggested edit has been approved".

Here's a [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1214160/reviewtaskresulttypes) to all the review task result types, their names, and human-readable descriptions, and a screenshot of the relevant entries in the table:

[image: Swapped descriptions]

Can this please be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the description were reversed. As of the new SEDE refresh they should be reversed again (ie: accurate).

> two wrong descriptions
> for review task result types
> reversed, now on point