# Grace period for submitting reviews on completed items doesn't work for "Close" reviews in the close queue

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

Normally, the system [provides a 15-minute grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322015/377214) on completed reviews, to allow users to submit a review if they loaded a task before it was completed but another user submits the final review before the user is able to submit theirs. This is to ensure that all users still get credit for their reviews even if the task gets completed from underneath them. However, this doesn't seem to apply for Close reviews in the close queue: one can't submit a review for closure if someone else who's reviewing at the same time casts the final vote to close.

A while ago, I was reviewing in the close votes queue, and was shown a review task of a question that had four close votes at the time it was shown. The question was clearly not a good fit for the site, so I proceeded to review as "Close", but while I was going through the motions to vote to close, the question got its fifth close vote from another user and I couldn't cast my vote because it was already closed.

As my close vote didn't go through since the question was already closed, I was unable to submit my review in favor of closure. I was therefore left with no choice but to either skip the review, which would make the review task not count toward my tasks reviewed, or review in favor of leaving open if I wanted that task to count, which would be incorrect and may lead me to getting a review suspension.

I imagine the same situation also happens in the reopen queue: one can't review for reopening if another reviewer casts the final reopen vote at the same time. A similar situation also occurs if someone casts the last vote externally (on the question itself, not through review): while that last vote would invalidate the review, it takes time for the system's scheduled task to do so, and the task would still be reviewable (overall) while I'm reviewing it, providing a similar grace period as above.

It's not within my control if someone else casts a vote while I'm reviewing, and it shouldn't deny me credit for the review. That's why the 15-minute grace period above exists, so everyone who's reviewing gets credit even if another user completes the review. It shouldn't be inconsistently not applied for these specific review types.

In summary, if a user is reviewing a close or reopen review task for a question that has already been closed/reopened, and the user can still submit reviews for it (the task hasn't been invalidated or the 15-minute grace period is in effect), then attempting to review as Close or Reopen should credit the user for the review (count them as having reviewed that way).

Comment: A similar case can happen with Suggested Edits, IIRC

Comment: There is a "related" issue in First Questions: If I cast the last close vote, then that takes effect and I can complete my review with the "Other action" button. However, if I "refresh" the view (inside the queue), then the item becomes "No longer reviewable".