# What makes you eligible to review certain items in a review queue?

Tags: support, review

[A previously asked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238698/does-the-review-queue-page-show-only-reviews-requiring-your-action-does-it-diff) addresses the situation of "Does the review queue page show only reviews requiring your action?" [The answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238699/365152) from [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) essentially said:

> Caching. And some complicated eligibility rules.

My question here is a follow-up in regard to the **eligibility rules**. Shog9's answer only alludes to them, without providing a complete explanation:

> ...But there are still some edge-cases where there'll be items in a queue that you aren't eligible to review but which are disqualified because of tests too expensive for the system to run until/unless you actually try to review them.

**What makes you eligible to review certain items in a review queue?**
*Are these rules related to locking a question for a [limited period of exclusivity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238897/suggested-edit-still-not-in-the-queue-after-1-hour/238898#238898)?*

Looking for some knowledgeable and credible sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limited period of exclusivity is one of the criteria that contributes to this, but there is quite a variety of other things that prevent you being able to review a task:

- The review is on a post you own. This makes you, as author, ineligible in *some* of the queues.
- You have already completed some sort of moderator action on the post in question. For example, if you've already voted/flagged to close a question, you won't then see it in the Close Votes queue even though a review task will be created. (This is a bit iffy across the queues.)
- Something happened to make the task invalid, but it hasn't been formally invalidated and removed from review yet.
- You've simply already reviewed that task, but it requires further input from more reviewers.
- You've clicked the skip button on the review (although you can technically still review this by finding the task again, it won't be shown to you again automatically).

Probably some other minor things, but this gives you a general idea of how tasks can exist in the system but you aren't allowed to participate.

Comment: I guess the word ***some*** in the first point means "all but Suggested Edits", right?

Comment: @iDebug I'd have to look into it more for sure, but I think Close and Reopen might also be exceptions. At least I see no reason why the author shouldn't be able to review those if they're otherwise eligible. I imagine most don't ever see those tasks though (especially a reopen task, given they probably would've done it already directly on the question).

Comment: "_although you can technically still review this by finding the task again_" That's not true for Low Quality Posts, see [my bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291299/349538). It would be nice if this bug could be fixed.

Comment: @DonaldDuck not relevant. The issue is with the back button, not with skipping.

Comment: @animuson while some of my questions here on Meta have been getting close votes, I'm pretty sure I haven't reviewed them in the queue.

Comment: What originally sparked my curiosity was being shown new reviews when I switched computers, and seeing people who hadn't reviewed in awhile being shown new reviews that I was not being shown (even during periods of fairly active checking the queue). However, this Q/A clarifies that finer point: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165266/are-certain-users-favored-the-opportunity-to-review-posts